# Flutter build MediaQuery is this a bug?

Tags: flutter

Problem with 'build'.

This problem took me quite a long time to find, because I was looking at the layout for the cause.
I'm unsure if a broke some rule with Flutter or alternatively if this is a bug, however I would like to know.
The following code does not work as I expected:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ///
  if (_wTextStyleDefault == null) {
    _wTextStyleDefault = TextStyle(
        color: _colorText,
        fontFamily: 'DS',
        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.5,
        decoration: TextDecoration.none);
  }
  debugPrint(
      'build: _wTextStyleDefault.fontSize = ${_wTextStyleDefault.fontSize}');
```

Running this in release mode results in the following:

```
flutter run --release
I/flutter ( 5209): build: _wTextStyleDefault.fontSize = 0.0
```

Running the very same program in debug mode results in the following:

```
flutter run
I/flutter ( 5464): build: _wTextStyleDefault.fontSize = 144.0
```

Flutter doctor comes up clean. Using the latest Flutter and Dart on Windows.
The problem is very easily solved by simple making the TextStyle variable a local variable and all works as expected.

I do understand that there are timing differences between debug and release mode.

Is there some known reason why the use of a global variable should cause a different result?

Comment: Are you sure you're not doing different things in debug and release, such as calling it from different parts of the app? Also, are you saying `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` is 0? I don't think I've seen that in any use case before. Is this on an emulator or a physical device? iOS or Android?

Comment: @Ovidiu. Nothing else different apart from what was stated. Android physical device. If you try it I presume you will get the same result. The result is as shown.